# SPSS Spearman test, how to determine significance?

Tags: spss, spearman-rho

I did a Spearman test on 2 ordinal values (likert scale), my hypothoses are as follows:

**Null Hypotheses:** There is a correlation between participants who view images as an important tool and 
participants that with images can learn in ways they can't with other means.

**Alternate Hypotheses:** There is no correlation between participants who view images as an important tool and 
participants that with images can learn in ways they can't with other means.

I get the following output:

[image]

I spent the last hour trying to figure out how to interpret these results, what does the `correlation coefficient = .536` mean? And what does `Sig=0.000035` mean when the alpha is 0.01?

How do I use these values to pick the correct hypotheses?

Comment: `my hopothoses are as follows`  I liked it very, honoustly!

Comment: Other way round. Null: correlation in the population is zero. Alternative: correlation is not zero. .536 is the observed correlation in your sample (sized N=53). Its observed significance (p-value) is .000035. Critical significance level (alpha-value) is .01. p<alpha, so the correlation is significant (it is therefore starred). Reject Null and assume Alternative.

Comment: `How do I use these values to pick the correct hypothoses?` Unfortunately, a hypothesis must be formulated in advance. In the present case, SPSS tested the default hypothesis for you. It was about the Null/Alternative I've outlined above, and the critical level to highlight "significant" correlations with two stars for you in the table was set to be .01.

Comment: Note that .536 is the correlation in your sample, not in the population. In population it is unknown, but due to the significant result you may deduce that it is greater than 0.

Comment: But you can have a null hypothoses that assumes a negative? For example: **Null Hypothoses:** There is no difference between the means
**Alternate Hypothoses:** There is a difference between the means that is statistically significant (unrelated to above question).

Comment: In your own interests, please note correct spelling: hypothesis, hypotheses.